# How to iterate through multiple databases using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis

I am trying to create an SSIS (Visual Studio 2013, SQL Server 2014) job which loops through roughly 150 databases; updating 4 tables in each database. These databases exist on 1 server.  Each location has their own database and these databases are a clone of each other.

I have read some walkthroughs saying to create an Execute SQL Task to collect all of the database names, followed by a foreach loop.  These walkthroughs have been high level and provided very little detail as to actual steps needed.

I am still pretty new to SSIS and have not run into this task before. None of my books cover this topic and unfortunately, no, I am not a VB or C# developer.  I was building this solution as a script, but was told to do it in SSIS rather than a stored procedure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**edit**

Following the walkthrough in the Wrox Book:  SSIS 2012, Chapter 4 containers, Foreach ADO Enumerator example, I was able to get the system to return a listing of each database I need to connect to via the Script Task.

Now that I have the Script Task providing me the Database names, I need to associate that with the Execute SQL Task for my update statements to work against the correct Database; However I do not know how to associate the Database name returned by the Script Task to be used in the Execute SQL Task.

[Image of SSIS project](http://s578.photobucket.com/user/wjm1/media/datacleanup_zps56ovkvm6.jpg.html?sort=3&o=0)

Comment: The solution you mentioned sounds exactly what you need.  What exactly are you having problems with?  Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Exactly, the high-level approach you described is perfect, so which step of that approach are you having a problem with, and what is your specific question about it?    Asking for a detail of every step is too broad a question for SO.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad for this site, you are definitely heading in the right direction though.  Hint: look into for/foreach loop containers.

Answer (score 0):

Take executesqltask and write the below query to it.

Create a variable with object datatype

assign that variable as output in executesql task

Then use foreachloop container and take the above variable as in put and assign some new variable(variable2) in container to take present db as output.

In properties of the connection manager, go to expressions and in connection string assign this(variable2) there which changes accordingly with loop container

then you can do your operations over there....

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
```